# Accessibility cells in UITableView blocked by section header

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, voiceover

So for my app I am trying to enable full VoiceOver accessibility support. Most of it is working fine, but Im running into some problems with some UITableViews. These tables have section headers and are set to UITableViewStylePlain so the section headers will appear on top of the list. This is all very much intended for the regular user, but for users with VoiceOver enabled I'm running into some problems. Currently, when scrolling to the next page, some elements appear to be displayed below the header of the section, which makes them near impossible to select. So far I've been unable to determine whether this is in fact expected behaviour and whether I can fix this without removing the headers altogether.

I've already verified that the scrolling works fine if I set the header height to 0 as well as made sure that the UITableView itself is not out of bounds. Therefore my best conclusion is that the section headers are displayed on top of the list elements, which thus become obscured by the section.

To illustrate:

Before scrolling

```
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= (start of list)
Section Header
.........................
Elem 1

.........................
Elem 2

.........................
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= (end of list)
```

After scrolling:

```
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
Section Header            (Elem 3 is here)

.........................
Elem 4

.........................
Elem 5
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
```

In case my code is relevant:

```
- (UIView *)tableView: (UITableView *) tableView viewForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger) section
{
    UIView *headerView = [UIView new];
    UIView *containerView = [UIView new];
    // Add stuff to container View
    headerView.frame = CGRectMake( 0.00f, 0.00f,    tableView.frame.size.width, someHeight);
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    containerView.frame = headerView.frame;
    [headerView addSubview: containerView];

    containerView.isAccessibilityElement = true;
    containerView.accessibilityLabel = accessibilityLabel;
    headerView.isAccessibilityElement = false;

    return headerView;
}

- (CGFloat) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView heightForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger) section
{
    return someHeight;
}
```

So, anyone know a way to fix this without fully rewriting the sectioning logic?

Comment: Does swiping left/right with VoiceOver enabled, not navigate through the cells in order?

Comment: Not for me/in my app unfortunately. Besides I have to assume that users might be scrolling up and down making them less aware of the potential elements they do not see.

Comment: It does _not_?! Are you sure that VoiceOver is enabled, that you are testing on a real device, and that you are performing quick left and right swipes with one finger? That is the basic navigational actions (at least one of them) for VoiceOver on iOS. If that doesn't work, then you have more severe problems than table headers possibly covering a table view cell.

Comment: It has been more than 3 years, but were you able to find a solution @Daeda?

Comment: I have same issue too